# What is the best memory utilization and efficiency considerations for simulating particles that are randomly created and removed?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, random, memory, sow-reap

I am wanting to run a simulation involving a varying number of "particles" (points defined by 2D coordinates $(x,y)$ within some region). At each time step, there is a probability that a new particle can be created, and a different probability that an existing particle can be removed. This means that the total number of particles will be changing. (The simulation will be more complicated, with the particles moving around, interacting with each other and the region boundary, etc., but for now this simplification is the issue I am currently facing I believe).

For now, the only information for each existing particle is its location, so the whole state of the simulation will just be a list of ordered pairs; however, the length of this list will be changing depending on the creation and removal of particles. What is the best way to set this up so that it runs as efficiently as possible without slowing down due to memory constraints (among other things?)

I know that AppendTo is not an efficient function to use, and that the Sow + Reap combination is better, but I am not sure how to apply that/if it applies here since I am not wanting to build up a monotonically growing list. I suppose I could create a list of ordered pairs with enough elements to hold the maximum number of particles I would expect given other parameters, but I didn't know if there would still be inefficiencies there as well.

Comment: First, make sure you measure (time and/or memory...) that this is in fact your current bottleneck. Second, please include some code. Example: I am guessing you have code that takes as input the current positions, the indices that you want to remove, the positions you want to add, and produces as output the new positions. If that is the case, and if this is your bottleneck, please include that code.

Comment: I would pre-allocate a big enough array. Then you only need to deal with indices.

Comment: You could give the particles strictly increasing integer-labels and use `Association` as container. It features `KeyDropFrom` that allows removal of particles and `AppendTo` is implemented quite efficiently for it. `Values` allows you to get the packed matrix of all positions in the `Association`. If you append only keys greater than already in the container, then then `Values` returns the positions in precisely the order of the integer-keys.

Comment: Probably you need many distance queries for you particles during the simulation. Then the bottleneck will be all-pairs checks, not the memory layout. In that case one would have to build a space partitioning tree to cull as many distance queries as possible.